# What does 'saw myself going' mean in the context?

Tags: meaning

What does 'saw myself going' mean here?

> I saw on the door surgery began at 8:30 and I ought to have guessed
>   there would be a lot of people as usual, but for some reason I just
>   **saw myself going** in and seeing the doctor straight off.

Comment: For easier reading, read "imagined" instead of "saw."  "I imagined/expected I would go in and see the doctor right away."

Comment: *Picturing* implies *hope* **not** *expectation*. Assuming you can imply either from the mental image. It's best to keep it to simply what was imagined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means something like "I expected that I would go in ..." It's not particularly an idiom in this sense.

Comment: To clarify, the bold words in the OP are misleading.  The entire remainder of the sentence is what the quoted person expected, not just "myself going".

Answer (score 20):

[The definition of *to see* that's being used here is](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/see)

> 3 a : to form a mental picture of : visualize

So you can parse this as

> I visualized (what did I visualize?)
>   myself (doing what?)
>   going in

Comment: +1 Yes, this. It is *picturing* yourself going in, not necessarily *expecting* yourself to go in. More likely, if something were to follow from what you had pictured, it would be *hoped*.

Comment: @JasonBassford "Picture one's self" is a great substitution for "see one's self." "Picture yourself in a boat on a river..." for example.

Answer (score 0):

In this sort of context what you're reading is commentary on a prediction, not literal experiences.

They constructed an erroneous scenario in their mind where they would be able to go straight into the doctor's office rather than, for example, waiting an hour.

This usage of See is almost always in a predictive scenario-driven context, similar to Oracles "seeing" the future.